# Whatsapp-Web.js disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, whatsapp

I'm using the whatsapp-web.js library and I don't know why but after a while it disconnects and lets me scan a new QR code. I would like that my devices stay logged in and don't to scan the QR code every time.
I use LocalAuth but I think it doesn't work on Heroku.

I try to make it work on Heroku or on other host.

```
const createSession = function (id, description) {
  console.log('Creating session: ' + id);
  const client = new Client({
    restartOnAuthFail: true,
    puppeteer: {
      headless: true,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process', // <-  doesn't works in Windows
        '--disable-gpu'
      ],
    },
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
      clientId: id
    })
  });


  const savedSessions = [
                         {"id":"123456","description":"exapmle1","ready":true}, 
                         {"id":"123457","description":"exapmle2","ready":true}
                        ]

   savedSessions.forEach(sess => {
      createSession(sess.id, sess.description);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't if it's the same issue
but i think you need to check after a while if there is an existing conection,
if not, u need to reinitialized the conection.

try it like this

```js
if (x?.pupBrowser?._connection) {
doSomthingWithConectedClient()}
else{
 client
      .initialize()
      .then( () => doSomthingWithConectedClient())

}
```